# Is it possible to connect to Azure Storage Account with Private Ednpoint from Databricks?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to connect to the Azure DataLake 2/Storage Account which is enabled with private endpoint from my Databricks Notebook, however getting error :

```
Caused by: StorageException: This Request is not Authorized to Perform this operation.
```

I tried adding Databricks IP addresses(found in Network Interface/ VNET attached with Databricks, but not sure if that's the one) in Firewall IP List to whilelist the requests from on-prem. But getting the same error. Is there a way to establish the connection with such configuration?

Comment: do you have "Blob Contributor" permission for that storage account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the same environment as you have done and tried to mount the storage account in Databricks notebook but got the same error “Unauthorized”.

[image]

**Solution:**

As we have created the storage account with private endpoint there is a firewall setup by default .  So, to fix that we need to have the vnet and the subnets that the databrick is using set inside it as shown below.

[image]

So after that when I mount the storage account it successfully gets mounted.

[image]

But again to read the files from the folder you have to Manage ACL’s for the container and also the files .

[image]

After this you can get the below output:

[image]

Same can be done for Files as well by doing a right click on the file that needs to be read from Databricks notebook.

[image]

You can test it in Databricks after you have added access control to the file:

[image]

**Note:** I have Used Service Principal(i.e. ADLStest) to use ADLS gen2 storage account from Databricks . That Service Principal should have “Storage Blob Data Contributor ” role assigned to it . And the Manage ACL's should be done for that service principal only.

**Reference:**

[Access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access.html#)

[Mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 Account in Databricks (mssqltips.com)](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6931/mount-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-databricks/)